# Conditional density when another conditional density is known

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I have hit upon the following wall:

I have three absolutely continuous random variables, $X, Y, Z$. $X$ ranges in all $\mathbb R$, while $Y,Z$ are non-negative. $Y$ and $Z$ are statistically dependent. $X$ is independent of both, in every sense.

I know the joint density $f_{YZ}(y,z)$, and the conditional density $f_{Y|Z}(y\mid z)$, as well as the marginal densities of all three.

Let $Q= X-Y$. $f_Q(q)$ is also available.

**I need to obtain the conditional density $f_{Q|Z}(q\mid z)$, or $f_{Z|Q}(z\mid q)$**.

For some reason, I am stuck, I mean totally stuck, probably a neurological glitch or something. It appears I need the joint density $f_{QZ}(q,z)$, but I cannot reach it.

Is there any hint out there?

Comment: In full generality, if $Q=X-Y$, then $$f_{Q,Z}(q,z)=\int_\mathbb R f_{X,Y,Z}(y+q,y,z)\,dy$$ hence, in your case, $$f_{Q,Z}(q,z)=\int_\mathbb R f_X(y+q)f_{Y,Z}(y,z)\,dy$$ and $$f_Z(z)=\int_\mathbb Rf_{Y,Z}(y,z)\,dy$$ which allows to deduce $f_{Q\mid Z}(q\mid z)$ as a ratio of integrals involving $f_X$ and $f_{Y,Z}$.

Comment: @Did. Thank you, that does it!